# Emacs VCS interface commits only one file

Tags: version-control, emacs, dvcs, commit, bazaar

When I commit changes with Emacs' built-in VCS interface (I use it with Bazaar) it commits only one file - that's open in current buffer.
So when I press C-c v v, enter message and C-c C-c, it does something like

```
bzr commit -m "my message" file/open/in.buffer
```

instead of

```
bzr commit -m "my message"
```

How to commit all changes with Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got an answer from identi.ca user https://identi.ca/mjog.

http://www.xsteve.at/prg/emacs_dvc/dvc.html - better frontend for DVCS.

Comment: just FYI - http://xtalk.msk.su/~ott/en/writings/emacs-vcs/EmacsDVC.html - article about DVC

Comment: Tried to use dvc, but... I like vc-mode better.  As @NikkiA says, and I expanded on, it *can* commit multiple files.

Answer (score 6):

If you commit from a vc-dir buffer rather than an individual file, then it will commit all changes (assuming the cursor is NOT pointing at a specific file), not just the single file. Use 'v' for vc-next-action on the directory buffer. Actions in a vc-dir buffer are related to the repository, rather than tied to a specific file.

Using an alternate front-end is also an option, as you've discovered, but sometimes it is still important to know how to do things with the base emacs distribution :)

Comment: And if you mark files, any action works on the marked files.  So, you can commit any subset of modified files with this too.  (Though I'm still missing something like "hg crecord" (a third-party extension, *not* the included "record") integrated into Emacs)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, the emacs VCS interface has always been file-based, i.e. it works per file rather than per change set. Therefore VCS is a poor fit for version control systems like SVN, GIT, ... where a revision is per repository rather than per file. Magit is a great git mode for emacs that works on change sets. There also seems to be a dedicated [bazaar mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/bazaar.el) available, which I assume also works per change set rather than per file.

Comment: See above for NikkiA's answer, the included interface *can* do changesets.  I know I've used it that way in 2009, not sure how much earlier it got that functionality.